# GetMaterial.router not working on getx 4.6.5

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-getx

I'm developing flutter web and try to run demo code getx on get 4.6.5 but when use Get.toNamed() i got error "Navigator.onGenerateRoute was null, but the route named "/second/id=3" was referenced."
Then i try get.to() but the url not change and reload page i can't back to page1
Here is my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp.router(
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
            participatesInRootNavigator: true,
            name: '/first',
            page: () => First()),
        GetPage(
          name: '/second/:id',
          page: () => Second(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: '/third',
          page: () => Third(),
        ),
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class First extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('page one'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.more),
          onPressed: () {
            Get.changeTheme(
                context.isDarkMode ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark());
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.toNamed('/second/id=3');
            },
            child: Text('next screen'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('page two ${Get.parameters["id"]}'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.toNamed('/third');
            },
            child: Text('next screen'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm newbie on flutter web hope to get help from everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, everyone. I resolve this by using `Get.rootDelegate.toNamed()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it like this:

```
child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.toNamed('/second/3');
            },
            child: Text('next screen'),
          ),
```

Comment: i got the same error

Comment: resolve by use Get.rootDelegate.toNamed()